# Collect2 error on destructor definition within a class

Tags: c++, class, tree

I get an error if I include the "~Binary_tree()" destructor. But when I remove it, everything compiles.

My node.h file

```
template<class T>
class Binary_tree
{
    private:
        void insert(T val, Node<T> *ptr);
        Node<T> *search(T val, Node<T> *ptr);
        Node<T> *root;

    public:
        Binary_tree()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }
        ~Binary_tree();
        void insert(T val);
        Node<T> *search(T val);
};
```

my main.cc

```
#include<iostream>
#include "node.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Binary_tree<char> tree;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined your destructor, only declared it. It should be:

```
~Binary_tree() { /*delete tree*/ }
```

What you see is actually a linker error, and not compile error. You might think that you have not defined also few other methods like `insert` or `search`and you get no error,... but they are not called in your code - so linker does not output error. On the other hand destructor in your example is called implicitly when `tree` object goes out of scope. If you dont add one yourself, compiler will create definition on its own - that is why you get no error when you remove declaration of `~Binary_tree();`. This compiler synthesized destructor will not free your tree, you have to do it on your own - or use shared ptrs.

Answer (score 0):

Template is replacement of macro, so template definition must be available at instantiation point. You should put definition of ~Binary_tree and all other methods to the template definition.